# Powershell - Regex, Replace and Save file

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, match

In a bunch of SVG files (same folder) I need to remove the **first** **3** **lines** or **even better** everything before the start-tag     `<svg ...`

Then I have `<a>`-Tags like this:

```
<a xlink:href="1">
```

All those occurences should be replaced in this style:

```
<a onClick="top.getLink(1)">
```

and then overwrite the according file with these changes.

In Notepad++ this pattern to search and replace the a-Tag works:

```
<a xlink:href\="(.*)">
```

And I can replace it with this to get the desired output:

```
<a onClick="top.getLink\(($1)\)">
```

But in Powershell I don't know the regex or general syntax well enough to pull this off.
The idea is to run this powershell script repeatedly and ideally ignore the files that had been processed before.

Can you show me an example how to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: if you have already working pattern in notepad++, why do you need PowerShell? you can run it on multiple files from npp.

Comment: try with this :- `'<a onClick="top.getLink\(($Matches[1])\)">'`

Answer (score 0):

The code for your problem with appropriate regEx will look like below with the use of the -replace:

```
    $yourText = '<a onClick="top.getLink(1)">'

    $yourText -replace '<a xlink:href\="(.*)">','<a onClick="top.getLink\(($1)\)">'
```

Try it out and let us know if this helps your case.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me: Thank you.

```
$regex = '<a xlink:href\="(.*)">'
$replace ='<a onClick="top.getLink($1)>'

$file = "C:\temp\abc.svg"
$firstLine = Get-Content $file -First 1

    if($firstLine -match '^<\?xml'){
    (Get-Content $file) | Select-Object -Skip 3 |
        Foreach-Object {$_ -replace $regex,$replace}  | 
        SET-Content $file
    }
    else{
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One option:

```
(Get-Content $file -raw) -replace '.+?(<svg.+)','$1' -replace '<a xlink:href="1">','<a onClick="top.getLink(1)">' |
Set-Content $file
```